# Where is code located wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I was told that in my theme oxygen which I am using for woocommerce that I needed to change the html in the following on the category page but I cannot for the life of me find it.

```
<div class="main">
<div class="laborator-woocommerce shop">
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="codenegar-shop-loop-wrapper">
        <div class="row">...</div>
        <!-- Here is the problem -->
        <div class="row">...</div>
        <!-- Here is the problem -->
        <div class="col-md-3 sidebar-env">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change to

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="laborator-woocommerce shop">
        <div class="row">...</div>
        <div class="codenegar-shop-loop-wrapper">
            <div class="row">...</div>
            <!-- Here is the change -->
            <div class="col-md-9">...</div>
            <!-- Here is the change -->
            <div class="col-md-3 sidebar-env">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

If you have a look at the source here http://212.159.70.57/karen/product-category/women/ you can see what I am trying to fix is the sidebar floating to bottom the below does fix it but i cant see how row is being generated in the source

Comment: You can override templates. http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Yes i no that but i been pulling my hair out for days tyring find this simple piece of code any ideas what template file cause all the ones i look at the row is not their its like its being produced dynamically

Comment: And i have said I am using a theme and trying to find it overides but cant locate where its adding the second row !

Comment: For future reference, if you use a decent text editor (such as [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) you can search entire folders. I usually look for an html class (ex: class="codenegar-shop-loop-wrapper" ). This will *drastically* help in locating specific pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having trouble finding this the file is called loop-start.php located in

\themes\oxygen\woocommerce\loop

You need to change line 15 above to reflect the above.